# ¿Como puedo insertar el ID de una tabla en otra?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

me he topado con un problemilla, estoy trabajando con PHP y MySQL y tengo un formulario que registra en dos tablas diferentes "Datos_Usuarios" y "Login", hasta aqui todo correcto pero en "Login" tengo un campo que se relaciona con "Datos_Usuarios" el cual se llama "Usuario_ID" y se relaciona con el ID de "Datos_Usuarios" como puedo obtener el ultimo ID de "Datos_Usuarios" para insertarlo justo en la siguiente consulta he intentado con muchas funciones y aun no he puedo hacerlo funcionar, adjunto codigo para dar una idea

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO Datos_Usuarios 
        (ID, Cliente_InternoID, Nombre, Telefono, Fecha_Nacimiento) 
        VALUES (NULL, 1, :Nombre, :Telefono, :Fecha_Nacimiento)');

$statement->execute(array(":Nombre"=>$Nombre, ":Telefono"=>$Telefono, 
":Fecha_Nacimiento"=>$Fecha_Nacimiento));

$ID = $statement->lastInsertId();

$statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO Login 
(ID, UsuarioID, Usuario, Pass) 
VALUES (NULL, :UsuarioID, :Usuario, :Pass)");

$statement->execute(array(":UsuarioID"=>$ID, ":Usuario"=>$Correo, ":Pass"=>$Pass));
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `lastInsertId()` es parte del driver PDO. No es parte del recurso `$statement`

Debes cambiar:

`$ID = $statement->lastInsertId();`

Por:

`$ID = $conexion->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono mejor de lo que esperaba

Comment: Que bueno que te sirva.